# Compile C extension During Travis CI Elixir Build

Tags: erlang, travis-ci, elixir, rebar

https://travis-ci.org/mmmries/sqlitex/builds/51889563#L96

I'm trying to setup Travis CI integration for my sqlite Elixir project. Currently the build is failing when trying to compile the C extension which is part of the [esqlite](https://github.com/mmzeeman/esqlite) dependency. The error message is coming back with

```
c_src/esqlite3_nif.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

So the compilation error is happening down in the rebar layer which I don't know much about. I haven't been able to replicate this build error outside of Travis so I'm not sure where to look next.

Comment: I would starting looking into gcc version on Travis-CI. Next, I would look into your rebar version and the one being used on esqlite. Given they use travis, it does work on some conditions. Maybe if you do "mix local.rebar" before installing dependencies it would work as it would likely use the same version as you have locally?

Comment: the gcc version is the same version [as the build for esqlite](https://travis-ci.org/mmzeeman/esqlite/jobs/49109236#L15). I also tried using `mix local.rebar --force` as an extra install step before the compile without no luck

Comment: Ohhhhh, it looks like the problem is with how I published the esqlite hex package. The tar file includes esqlite3_nif.o already compiled (on an OSX machine) which is why it works fine when I try to install and compile on another OSX machine, but it fails on the ubuntu image that travis is using.

Can anyone point me to some documentation on how to properly publish a hex package for a rebar project that should be compiled on the client machine?

Comment: You just don't want to include the "priv" directory (or the directory the .so file is compiled to). You can configure which files are part of the package by specifying the "files" option inside your package configuration for hex.

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/master/mix.exs#L51-L56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build is now working correctly: https://travis-ci.org/mmmries/sqlitex/builds/52085658

The problem was that I messed up the esqlite dependency upstream. I published a copy of the rebar project to hex.pm so I could specify it as a dependnecy, but I accidentally included the compiled "c_src/*.o" files in the hex package, but these files should be compiled locally on the client machine.

The ubuntu image on travis was trying to use the existing .o files that were compiled on an OSX machine which is why the file format was wrong.